# Model attribute proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Lets say we have a `foos` table with a column `bar`. Now we rename the column to `bar_primary` and add another - `bar_secondary`. We want to dispatch the read/write behavior of `bar` to some of the two attributes.

I was hoping that something like:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def bar
    read_condition ? bar_primary : bar_secondary
  end

  def bar=(value)
    if write_condition
      self.bar_primary = value
    else
      self.bar_secondary = value
    end
  end
end
```

Would do the trick, however something like:

```
foo['bar'] = 'baz'
```

Will break it. Now I could implement `[]=`, but this is beginning to smell.

Is there some rails magic I'm unaware of that might be useful in this case?

Comment: Deleted my answer - I think this question falls under *unclear what you are asking* unless you can come up with a more tangible example of the actual problem you are trying solve.

Comment: @max, though the original use case is not mentioned, I think the question is more than clear. A proxy/dispatcher, that behaves as persisted attribute as much as possible.

Comment: can't you replace `foo['bar'] = 'baz'` by `foo.bar = 'baz'`? I think `foo['bar'] = 'baz'` goes straight to the columns, so it will skip the setter :(

Answer (score 0):

Aliases tend to cover this kind of requirement, but I'm not sure about conditional aliases.

Have a look at [`alias_attribute`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/alias_attribute)

Comment: I tried `alias_attribute`, but it doesn't seem to handle indexing. It wont work with conditionals anyway.